# Draw.io: How to move selected arrow object

Tags: app.diagrams.net

For any object, after I select it, I can move it by dragging with the mouse click. However this is not working for a simple straight arrow object. When I try to move it, the waypoints are getting changed rather than the object itself moving.

Answer (score 0):

I realized if you create an arrow object using the sidebar (General library) then you can move the arrow once you select. However you cannot do this when you create an arrow object by extending from the 'x' placeholders of another object.

So to be able to select and move an arrow object, please sure to create it using the sidebar (General library) rather than extending from the 'x' placeholders.